# Access hidden "root-only" folders on Finder

Tags: macos, finder, root

Is there any way to view folders that require root access to open, in Finder? I can open them with `sudo` in the terminal but it would be good if some setting or script allowed me to look at hidden folders in Finder? I am running OSX 10.9.

[image]

Comment: Simplest would be to add yourself to the ACL. I can do it in BatChmod, but for terminal you'll need to wait for someone smarter than me to answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is useful to quit the Finder application and reopen as the root user. You can quit the Finder application by entering the following command in a Terminal application window.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to quit'
```

Below is the Terminal application commands for opening as root user. *I assume here that you have first quit any previous opened Finder applications.*

If using Mavericks (OS X 10.9) or Yosemite (OS X 10.10):

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder 2>&1 | logger &
```

If using Yosemite (OS X 10.10) or El Capitan (OS X 10.11):

```
sudo login -f root
/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder 2>&1 | logger &
exit
```